# Nginx Enable HTTPS/SSL when forwarding to other URL

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, nginx, https, amazon-ec2

Currently, I'm working with an AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance, running a Node.js app on port 3000, that has an Nginx reverse proxy. I have been trying to enable HTTPS and add a SSL certificate and I've been successful in that I don't get any errors in the nginx.conf file. However, I am redirecting my main website, "example.com" to the public DNS of the AWS server and when I try to load the "http://example.com" or "https://example.com" page, I get a "Unable to Connect" error from Firefox, which is my testing browser. Also when I run `sudo nginx -t`, there are no syntactical errors in the configuration file and when I check the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` file it is empty. Below is my current nginx.conf file.

Update: I changed server_name from `example.com` to the public DNS of my server, lets call it `amazonaws.com`. Now, when I type in `https://amazonaws.com` the page loads and the SSL certificate shows up when running the website through ssllabs.com. However, when I type in `amazonaws.com` or `http://amazonaws.com` I get a blank page like before.

```
user root;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  # max_clients = worker_processes * worker_connections / 4
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;

  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;

  # backend applications
  upstream nodes {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 64;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com.key;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    server_name example.com;

    # everything else goes to backend node apps
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://nodes;

      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_set_header Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give this server definition

```
server {
listen 80;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

a server_name (eg amazonaws.com) as well.